# Is there a way to remove all attributes from an XSLT attribute set when overriding that attr set?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I'm working with some third-party XSLT that makes heavy use of attribute sets for transforming XML to various forms of XSL:FO. Example:

notes.xsl:

```
<xsl:template match="note">
    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="noteAttrs">
        <!-- This is a pretty big template with lots of xsl:choose/xsl:if/etc. -->
     </fo:block>
<xsl:template>

<xsl:attribute-set name="noteAttrs">
    <xsl:attribute name="margin-left">10px</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="margin-right">8px</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="margin-top">5px</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">10pt</xsl:attribute>
    <!-- several other attributes -->
</xsl:attribute>
```

The idea is that I import this XSLT, redefining the attribute sets as I see fit. If I just need a different font size for a given .fo document...

```
<xsl:import href="notes.xsl"/>
<xsl:attribute-set name="noteAttrs">
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">12pt</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute>
```

The problem is that sometimes I need to flat out remove attributes (i.e. so I inherit from the containing fo:block), or a given fo document is going to be so different that it would be easier to start fresh instead of merge my attribute set with the one from notes.xsl. Is there a way in XSLT 2.0 to do that without reproducing the entire template for note and specifying a different attribute set on the fo:block? I guess I'm looking to be able to do something like this:

```
<xsl:import href="notes.xsl"/>
<xsl:attribute-set name="noteAttrs" merge_with_imported_attr_set="false">
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">12pt</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute>
```

I can't switch to an XSLT 3.0 processor immediately, but if there's something new in 3.0 that enables this, I'd love to know about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attribute sets are not very widely used and to answer your question I had to look at the spec to refresh my memory. I don't think there is any way of achieving what you are wanting; you can't really override an attribute set in an importing stylesheet, you can only supplement it. In a well-designed XML vocabulary there is usually an attribute value you can set that is equivalent to omitting the attribute, but if that's not the case then you are stuck.